# Replacing an intrinsic Mathematica function by some other function

Tags: replacement, special-functions

I want to express the Hypergeometric2F1 series (which is an intrinsic function of Mathematica )  wherever it appears by its definition.

Where ever this function appears with whatever the arguments I want the following replacement,

```
Hypergeometric2F1[arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4]-> (Pochhammer[arg1,n]Pochhammer[arg2,n] (arg4)^n)/(Pochhammer[arg3,n]n!)
```

Note the summation over n is not there, as I want simplify the Pochhammer symbols.
Demo problem :

```
 [(Gamma[c + m] Gamma[-a2 - b2 + c + m] Hypergeometric2F1[a2, 
  1 + a2 - c - m, 1 + a2 + b2 - c - m, (-1 + y)/y]) 
+ (Gamma[a2 + b2 - c - m] Gamma[c + m] Hypergeometric2F1[
  1 - b2, -b2 + c + m, 1 - a2 - b2 + c + m, (-1 + y)/y])]
*(Pochhammer[a1, m] Pochhammer[b1, m])/(m! Pochhammer[c, m])
```

I tried with the following. Defined a function g as follows

```
g[x1_, y1_, z1_, w1_, n_] := (
 Pochhammer[x1, n] Pochhammer[y1, n] (w1)^n)/(Pochhammer[z1, n] n!);
```

and applied  to the expression as,

```
Hypergeometric2F1[x1___, y1___, z1___, w1___] -> g[x1, y1, z1, w1, n]
```

This didn't work.

Comment: Have you also tried `RuleDelayed` as in `Hypergeometric2F1[x1___, y1___, z1___, w1___] :> g[x1, y1, z1, w1, n] `? However, that will only work if `Hypergeometric2F1[x1, y1, z1, w1]` does not immediately evaluate to something else.

Comment: I just tried that. It works. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.